# FATAL ERROR : unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda (dual boot installation of Ubuntu with W10, both OS in separate drives)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, 20.04

I am not a complete beginner to Linux based systems but this one baffles me -
I tried a lot of ways from other forums since 3 days but none of them seem to work.

I am installing Ubuntu 20.04 Budgie onto my Dell G3 which has - 
16GB RAM and two drives - 256GB SSD (W10) and 1TB HDD(where I want to install Ubuntu).

My Windows is based on UEFI so according to what I read on various forums, my Ubuntu should also use UEFI.

Everything else works out fine.
I will describe the partitions I make normally 
in the 100 GB of free space I have in /dev/sda (which is my HDD; 
I was told not to touch /dev/sdb -> W10)

```
30GB root partition (mount point -> /)       (type -> ETX4)               (primary partition)
20GB swap partition                          (type -> swap area)          (primary partition)
49.5GB home partition (mount point -> /home) (type -> EXT4)               (primary partition)
531MB ESP                                    (type -> EFI file partition) (primary partition)
```

When I proceed, everything goes normally but when ot tries to install grub, there is always an error message -

```
FATAL ERROR - unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda.
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: You should already have an ESP on your SSD (where W10 is installed). You should never need to make a separate ESP partition. And what exactly is 'ETF4'?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, it's ext4 Aas you might have guessed

Comment: I tried that too - without any efi partition in my hdd @Paul Benson, it won't work.

Comment: In your question, delete the description of your Ubuntu partitions. Then boot into Live Ubuntu. Run from terminal `sudo parted -l`, and paste that output into your question in place of what you just deleted.